# split excel file based on the number of sheets using python

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am writing a python script that read excel file and split it into multiple files based on the number of sheets. for that i am using **xlwings** package

The Problem is that when i run the script it crash and display the below error:

> with xw.App(visible = False) as app: AttributeError: **enter**

## code

```
from pathlib import Path
import xlwings as xw



base_dir = Path(__file__).parent
output_dir = base_dir / "output" 
output_dir.mkdir(parents=True,exist_ok=True)

excel_file = "O:/WorkFiles/test.xlsm"

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:

    wb = app.books.open(excel_file)

    for sheet in wb.sheets:
        wb_new = app.books.add()

        sheet.copy(after=wb_new.sheets[0])
        wb_new.sheets[0].delete()
        wb_new.save(f"{sheet.name}.xlsx")
        wb_new.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there was an error in this line:

*with xw.App(visible=False) as app:*

But without it, your code works. Have fun

```
from pathlib import Path
import xlwings as xw



base_dir = Path(__file__).parent
output_dir = base_dir / "output" 
output_dir.mkdir(parents=True,exist_ok=True)

excel_file = "O:/WorkFiles/test.xlsm"

app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = xw.Book(excel_file)


 for sheet in wb.sheets:
     wb_new = app.books.add()
     sheet.copy(after=wb_new.sheets[0])
     wb_new.sheets[0].delete()
     wb_new.save(f"{sheet.name}.xlsx")
     wb_new.close()
```

Comment: i tried your answer and you were right this line was the error but its from the official documentation... But now it display this error:: `sheet.copy(after=wb_new.sheets[0])    AttributeError:'Sheet' object has no attribute 'copy'`

Comment: Then you need to update xlwings.

Comment: yes i already tried this option i updated and its the latest version 0.27.3

Comment: when i debug the code it crash and display `could not load source '<COMObject  <unknown>>':Source unavailable`

Comment: Make sure that your data and paths are correct, in my test scenario the code worked fine and splitted the sheets into separate files.

Comment: i am using the script on an **offline pc** can this be the problem ??

Comment: If your Excel data are on a server or similar of course this could be the cause and the files might not be read in. You could try out the code by pasting the files to the same directory and it should work. Please tick the answer as correct as it works in general. The new problem is a separate to your original question

Comment: no its in the same directory where the script but the computer is not connected to the internet

Comment: This shouldn´t be the problem, but I can´t help you with that, maybe open a new kernel and try again, but your initial question is solved, please consider marking it as answered.